# Issues with Apache ServiceMix and javax.transaction

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix, aries

I am having an issue with Apache ServiceMix (7.0.0.M1).  I start up a fresh service mix (clean) and simply install the transaction feature:

```
karaf@root>feature:install transaction
```

This puts the Aries Transaction Blueprint into a GracePeriod:

```
224 | GracePeriod |  80 | 1.1.1                              | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint 
225 | GracePeriod |  80 | 2.1.0                              | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
```

This keeps my apps I install later that require the javax transaction api from starting.  Is there a workaround for this issue?  I had the same issues when just using karaf 4.0.3 and trying to instal camel and transaction.

Below you'll find a listing of all bundles (the basic service mix + those added by installing the transaction feature above).  Notice the failure due to the GracePeriod timeout.

```
karaf@root>list 
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50 
 ID | State   | Lvl | Version                            | Name 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
10 | Active  |  50 | 5.13.0                             | activemq-karaf 
11 | Active  |  50 | 2.6.3                              | Jackson-annotations 
12 | Active  |  50 | 2.6.3                              | Jackson-core 
13 | Active  |  50 | 2.6.3                              | jackson-databind 
23 | Active  |  50 | 3.1.4                              | activeio-core 
24 | Active  |  50 | 5.13.0                             | activemq-camel 
25 | Active  |  50 | 5.13.0                             | activemq-osgi 
40 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-blueprint 
41 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-catalog 
42 | Active  |  80 | 2.16.2                             | camel-commands-core 
43 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-core 
44 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-cxf 
45 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-cxf-transport 
46 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-jms 
47 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-spring 
48 | Active  |  50 | 2.16.2                             | camel-xstream 
49 | Active  |  80 | 2.16.2                             | camel-karaf-commands 
51 | Active  |  50 | 3.2.2                              | Apache Commons Collections 
53 | Active  |  50 | 3.3.0                              | Commons Net 
54 | Active  |  50 | 1.6.0                              | Commons Pool 
55 | Active  |  50 | 2.4.2                              | Apache Commons Pool 
93 | Active  |  50 | 2.0.0                              | geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec 
94 | Active  |  50 | 1.0.1                              | geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec 
99 | Active  |  50 | 3.4.6                              | ZooKeeper Bundle 
129 | Active  |  80 | 2.0.9                              | Apache MINA Core 
132 | Active  |  50 | 7.0.0.M1                           | Apache ServiceMix :: ActiveMQ :: Camel 
133 | Active  |  50 | 7.0.0.M1                           | Apache ServiceMix :: ActiveMQ :: Service 
136 | Active  |  50 | 1.6.1.5                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: dom4j 
138 | Active  |  50 | 1.9.2.1                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jasypt 
142 | Active  |  50 | 1.1.0.4                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jdom 
143 | Active  |  50 | 2.3.0.2                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: kxml2 
156 | Active  |  50 | 1.7.0.6                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: velocity 
160 | Active  |  50 | 1.1.4.c                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: xpp3 
161 | Active  |  50 | 1.4.8.1                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: xstream 
172 | Active  |  50 | 3.18.0                             | Apache XBean :: Spring 
201 | Active  |  50 | 0.6.4                              | JAXB2 Basics - Runtime 
214 | Active  |  50 | 2.11.0.v20140415-163722-cac6383e66 | Scala Standard Library 
221 | Active  |  80 | 1.2.0                              | CDI APIs 
222 | Active  |  80 | 1.2                                | javax.interceptor API 
223 | Active  |  80 | 1.2                                | javax.transaction API 
224 | Failure |  80 | 1.1.1                              | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint 
225 | Failure |  80 | 2.1.0                              | Apache Aries Transaction Blueprint
226 | Active  |  80 | 1.3.0                              | Apache Aries Transaction Manager 
227 | Active  |  80 | 1.0.2                              | Apache Felix Coordinator Service 
228 | Active  |  80 | 1.0.0.2                            | Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: javax.inject
```

I have cross posted to the apache mailing lists as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the spring-tx feature installs the jta 1.1 spec bundle. The aries transaction bundles require the new jta 1.2 spec though. So they do not find the TransactionManager which is bound to the wrong spec version.

This is caused by an error in the karaf spring-tx feature. The feature should depend on the jta 1.1 spec with dependency=true. This allows the karaf resolver to choose a different bundle providing suitable capabilities.

I have documented this issue in [KARAF-4358](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-4358). The issues is solved on master and the 4.0.x branch. So it will be delivered in karaf 4.0.5. You can fix you karaf distro by editing the feature file in the system dir in the same way I did.